# Extract Best Model's Formula from bestglm Package in R

Tags: r, glm

In R you can use the `bestglm` package to run all subset regressions and select the "best" model based on criterion that you specify.

A reproducible example:

```
require(xlsx)
require(bestglm)
lbw <- read.xls("http://www.umass.edu/statdata/statdata/data/lowbwt.xls")
## Prepare data
lbw.for.best.logistic <- within(lbw, {
    id   <- NULL        # Delete
    bwt  <- NULL
    race <- NULL
    ptl  <- NULL
    ftv  <- NULL

    y    <- low         # bwt into y
    low  <- NULL        # Delete bwt
})

## Reorder variables
lbw.for.best.logistic <-
    lbw.for.best.logistic[, c("age","lwt","race.cat","smoke","preterm","ht","ui","ftv.cat","y")]

## Perform
res.best.logistic <-
    bestglm(Xy = lbw.for.best.logistic,
            family = binomial,          # binomial family for logit
            IC = "AIC",                 # AIC chosen to select models
            method = "exhaustive")
```

Now, what I want to do is to extract the regression formula from the best result, so that I can pass it along to another statistical procedure in my function.

The best model is stored in `res.best.logistic$BestModel`, however the formula stored in the `str()` of that object is simply a call to `y~.` not the actual best model selected.

Is there a way to exact the best model's formula?

Comment: You are missing a package or two here

Comment: @DavidAreburg Oh, `xlsx` to use `read.xlsx`. Fair enough. Any others?

Comment: `rjava` too it seems... Because I failed to install it and was too lazy to install all the dependencies it needed

Comment: @DavidArenburg yea, `rJava` may be a dependency of `xlsx` or something, but it's not a library used here. You can get around `read.xlsx` with `read.table`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `formula`:

```
formula(res.best.logistic$BestModel)
```